# Java Server alway returning same message

Tags: java, serversocket

This is the first time that I do Socket programming and I made a client program and a Server program, and the server just send a simple message to the Client.
The problem is that when i change the message it will again display the old message.

This is the Client

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Client extends JFrame {

public static final int  PORT = 49998;

    Client(){
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();
        JTextField txt = new JTextField(20);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Send");

        window.add(thePanel);
        thePanel.add(txt);
        thePanel.add(btn);

        window.setSize(400,400);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setTitle("Client");
        window.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){     
        new Client();

        Socket conect;
        String ip;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter you're IP adress: ");
        ip = sc.nextLine();

        try{
            conect = new Socket(ip,PORT);
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader    (conect.getInputStream()));
            String line = read.readLine();
            if(line == null){
                System.out.println("Error reading from server");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(line);
            read.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Can't connect to server");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the Server

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Server {

    static PrintWriter pw;

    Server(){

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();
        JTextField txt = new JTextField(20);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Send");

        window.add(thePanel);
        thePanel.add(txt);
        thePanel.add(btn);

        window.setSize(400,400);
        window.setTitle("Server");
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Server();

        ServerSocket server;
        Socket connection;
        int port = 49998;

        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            while(true){
                connection = server.accept();
                sendMsg(connection);
            }           
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Problem connection to client");
        }

    }

    public static void sendMsg(Socket con){

        try{
            pw = new PrintWriter(
                con.getOutputStream());
            pw.println(" this actually work");
```

//this is the message if I change the conten of this it wont work anymore unless i change the port
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.print("Error connceting to client");
            }
        }

```
}
```

I haven't do anything with the JFrame yet so don't pay attention to it.

Comment: If you haven't done anything in the JFrame why did you post it? For future questions, you should try to only include relevant code. See [mcve] for more details.

Comment: `readLine()` returning null is not an error. It is a peer disconnect.

Comment: Thanks, now I have changed the port and it displays a new message but only the first time, so the program displays one message per port what do I have to change in my code to fix this?

Comment: I am not quite sure that I understand what you are trying to achieve. If you want to have the server send multiple messages, you need to program it to do so. If you want to want to have more than one client connect to the server and get the message, you need to make your server handle multiple client socket objects.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it works just right for me.

I mean... as per the code you posted I assume you are changing the message in source code and restarting server, right?

I suspect you just didn't stop your first server process so that it keeps the port busy and it keeps responding.

Here's what I do:

1. Compile server (your code as is)
2. compile client (your code as is)
3. run server at command prompt (open console and run java Server)
4. run client at a different command prompt (open console and run java Client)
5. in Client console insert ip address as requested (127.0.0.1)
6. Client console displays "Those this actually work"
7. Stop Client (Ctrl-C at Client's console)
8. Stop Server (Ctrl-C at Server's console)
9. Edit Server.java: Modify Server's message ("Those this actually work" -> "Different message") and save
10. Compile Server
11. repeat step 3 to 5
12. Client console displays "Different message"

I suspect you are missing step 8... can you double check? (In this case you should see the message "Problem connection to client" in server console)

Answer (score 0):

Close everything. The application tells the operating system it will listen on a specific port ... till it closes.

```
    try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port)) {
        while (true) {
            try (Socket connection = server.accept()) {
                sendMsg(connection);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Problem connection to client");
            }
        }           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem connection for server");
    }
```

The try-with-resources will take care of closing.